# Count rows matching index in another data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames.

The first describes a set of households:

```
#df1
street   house     etc
     1       1     ...
     1       2     ...
     2       1     ...
     2       2     ...
     2       3     ... 
     3       1     ...
```

The second describes the individuals who live in those houses

```
#df2
street   house   person     etc
     1       1        1     ...
     1       1        2     ...
     1       2        1     ...
     1       2        2     ...
     1       2        3     ...
     3       1        1     ...
```

I would like to add a new column to df1 called "member_count" and populate this column with the number of rows in df2 matching both "street" and "house". What is the most readable way of accomplishing this with base R?

Comment: `library(dplyr); df1 = df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% group_by(street, house) %>% summarise(member_count=n()), by=c("street","house"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(table(df2$street, df2$house))
names(tmpdf) <- c("street", "house", "member_count")
df1 <- merge(df1, tmpdf, by = c("street", "house"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, perhaps the easiest way is

```
df1$membercount <- mapply(function(s,h) nrow(df2[df2$street==s & df2$house==h,]),
                           df1$street,df1$house)

df1
  street house membercount
1      1     1           2
2      1     2           3
3      2     1           0
4      2     2           0
5      2     3           0
6      3     1           1
```